# Compile glibc without TLS support

Tags: linux, pthreads, glibc, libc

I read on the GNU web page (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html) that glibc can be compiled without the TLS support by using the option '--without-tls'. So I did, using the following command:

```
../configure  --prefix=/home/me/glibc-2.19/build/ --without-tls
```

and then

```
make
```

but apparently such a flag does not have the desired effect given that I can still see the sections .tdata and .tbss in the libc.so.6 object using readelf. Why is this happening? Is that option merely ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The option `--without-tls` was added here:

```
2002-02-06  Ulrich Drepper  <drepper@redhat.com>

        * configure.in: Add --without-tls option.
...
```

and removed here:

```
2011-09-11  Ulrich Drepper  <drepper@gmail.com>

        * configure.in: Remove --with-tls option.
...
```

The manual has not been updated to reflect that.